# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess ORA-12899 - Value too large for column

Tags: c#, oracle, ora-12899

I'm getting an 'ORA-12899 - Value too large for column (actual: 5, maximum:  4)' that I can't track down. I'm doing textbook parametized insert using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess provider in C#.  Has anybody seen anything like this?

What we're doing looks like:

```
var commandText = "insert into MyTable ([a ton of variables])   values(:A,:B,..........)";
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(commandText, connection))
    {
         for (the ton of variables there are to insert whose values are in a collection)
         command.Parameters.Add(theVariableName, theVariableValue);
    }
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Any thoughts? I checked a number of other answers, but with no luck.

Comment: What is it that you can't track down? Which input is too large for the column? What are the column data type and sizes in `MyTable`? If you don't know, run `define MyTable` to find out. Narrow it down - which column is `varchar2(4) (or perhaps char(4) or number(4))?

Comment: It turned out to be an ordering problem. I thought by adding the field names the order wouldn't matter. Turns out that it does. See Chris's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting command.BindByName=true.

The issue could be with the order with which you're adding the parameters in your for "(the tons of variables...)" loop. There is a parameter in the OracleCommand "BindByName" which defaults to false, meaning that it will ignore your variable name in the OracleParameter you're creating and just rely on the order in which you add them.   So if your variables are being added out of order, you will definitely need to set command.BindByName=true.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that was the issue. I would never have guessed that default value.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the creation of your database where you had defined the size of the attribute as 4. Alter the table and increase that.